# Epson TM-T88V formatting issues

Tags: ubuntu, printer

I set up a little machine running Ubuntu Server 12.04 with an Epson TM-T88V plugged into it directly. At first I was able to print fine (using `lp`) but the auto-cutter wasn't working. I realized it just wasn't using the correct PPD file that was included with the driver, so once I set the printer to use that cutting started working fine.

However, once I got it using the right PPD file the text is printing so light it's almost hard to read. When I tried to pass ESC/POS commands directly to it it was essentially like I'd gone back to the original situation (dark text, no cut).

This is really my first foray into thermal printers, so my apologies if I'm missing something simple. Am I going about this the completely wrong way? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.